# Species where female dies after childbirth

Tags: society

Let's take a species of aliens that has almost all females that die after childbirth (like, polymelia rare). How would females be treated?

All I need to know is that if there would be a plausible explanation for a pregnant Shinuy woman to:
1: Be allowed to vacation on another planet (Earth) unaccompanied (don't worry, the teleportation is safer here) and come back freely.
2: Have "sculpting" (altering another organism, something that she does to a human child as a gift to his parents for helping her) be something that she would not feel any guilt for (because I assume there would be something about "sculpting" being off limits for females, culturally)

Basically, I am starting out with a premise and need an explanation. I don't need to know anything else. I only want to know about culture, because that is more important.

Comment: See *Minerva* by James P Hogan. His alternate-universe has a nicer planet where Mars goes, and the race there has females (including the sentient species) that expire giving birth to a litter that includes 1 male and a bunch of females. They have radial symmetry;  I don't remember what degree.

Comment: There are species on Earth where the mother dies after childbirth.  One I'm thinking of offhand is a species of octopus where the mother spends all of her remaining energy after birth protecting the eggs and fanning them to keep circulation of oxygen rich water going.

Comment: @JDługosz The Minervans have hexagonal symmetry.  And momma dies because there's no disconnect between her blood supply and the fetus--she bleeds out.  (At least until humans introduced the idea of quickly clamping the blood vessels involved after birth.)

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested to read [The Clockwork Rocket](http://www.tor.com/2011/07/08/greg-egans-the-clockwork-rocket/). It was part of the premise along with some strange physics.

In the story the female effectively divides into four children (usually two male-female pairs of “co’s”) and dies in the process, leaving the male to raise the children.

> The idea of “reproductive freedom” takes on a whole new meaning when the female is guaranteed to die when giving birth. Some females refuse this fate and run away, but even then there’s a chance that they might spontaneously conceive, so there’s also a black market for an illegal contraceptive drug and a network of independent women to support it.

Relationships involving a partner who can continue to provide care become far more important in society since there is no such thing as a single mother. The society is likely to be far more patriarchal since so many women would die young hence very few would survive long enough to climb into senior positions.

Also in order for your species to be stable since there can only be one birth almost all births must involve twins at a bare minimum and more likely triplets or higher. Otherwise the population would halve every generation.

Comment: The last portion of this answer is very important to note. A species whose females die at childbirth must have children in groups to maintain a stable population. And, unless something has changed of late...the litter size must be large. During the developmental stages of their civilization, mortality rates would be high...so birth rates must be high to compensate.

Comment: Guildsbounty, of this I take note.

Comment: Good point that the problem of single mothers would be finally solved. ;) But as pointed out @guildsbounty for early survival of specie, the default birth rate would have to be huge. Actually, it would lead to a more developed society that would rather actually officially encourage contraception.

Answer (score 3):

An obvious implication is that all females produce litters rather than single offspring (twins, triplets, or probably many more). The reproductive pattern must have developed early in the species' history, predating civilization. Then the classic high mortality rate among the young would have seriously imperiled the continued existence of the species. This would probably have required the development of profoundly protective behaviors in the parents to protect the developing young, extending well beyond the sort of protection of the very young normally seen in terrestrial animals. A guess would be that family/herd units would be extremely strong.

I can't think of a good justification why it would have developed, but it also probably implies a considerable imbalance in sex ratios, with many more female offspring than males.

It's worth pointing out that the reverse situation (suicidal mating by males) is often seen in insects, and also in a few mammals. See, for instance, http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2454713/What-way-Male-marsupial-sex-death-intensive-14-hour-mating-sessions-final-fortnight.html

EDIT - To address your question directly, I'd have to suggest that the pregnant female is somehow an outcast, with no family/sibling circle to take her in and raise her young. Given how important such structure must be, she must have been on the losing end of a political struggle of some sort, and her being "allowed" to travel while pregnant is actually a cold-blooded decision to end her bloodline. She will give birth, then die, leaving her children unattended. Either that or she is considered some sort of deviant.

Political upheaval would seem likely as a consequence of the social bonding required to raise young, by producing extremely cohesive family units, with an attendant sense of separation from other such groups. Particularly as technology improves, this us/them separation would produce increasingly vicious conflict between the various clans.

In this reading, sculpting is something she would select to give her children a chance at survival, although exactly what changes would help are obviously up to you. Presumably, young aliens are pretty-well able to care for themselves, since nursing would not obviously arise as a care mechanism, unless the maternal death phenomenon is part of the standard physiology of the alien world. In that case, you'd expect that it might develop as a response to the presence of young who need protection.

Comment: Does not answer question. Was edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Certain death after childbirth would make having a child the definition of "a big commitment". Sort of like when a convict is on death row they get to choose their last meal, I think on this world the woman would be able to ask for whatever they liked before conceiving a child. So if she demanded she went to another planet unaccompanied, then that's what she'd get. However she would probably have to guaruntee the safety of the child somehow if this planet was in any way dangerous.

Similar to China preferring males when they had the 1 child rule, there would definitely be more preference about the characteristics of a child when women are giving up their lives for them. This would be encouraged by everyone and I think would be a natural mindset of society, and therefore no guilt would be felt for "sculpting" a child.

Comment: Sorry, didn't specify that I was talking about a human child being sculpted, as a gift to another human.

Comment: She's giving up her life to give a child as a present? I guess she would have to owe that person her life or have done that person some serious wrong! Might need some more information on why she'd feel guilty anyway...

Comment: No, you don't understand! She is already pregnant, and she helps out the pregnant wife of one human who helped her (she understands human culture enough) by ensuring that he will grow and be predisposed to things considered desirable by American humans.

Comment: If I don't understand it is because I'm not a mind reader and you haven't specified this information in your question... I would add it if you want more relevant answers.

Comment: I apologise, I just misunderestimated how much information I gave. Shinuy don't lose anything from sculpting.